# Code is ignoring IF command in C, Issues with FOR

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I had posted on here before, but I was never able to get the help I needed.
I'm working on a school project and I can not get my program to work properly.

The program should prompt the user to enter the number of gallons used and
the number of miles driven for each of the 3 tanks of gas. The program should
then calculate and display the miles per gallon obtained for each tank. Once
processing is complete for the 3 tanks, the program will calculate the overall
mileage(total gallons / total miles) and display a friendly "Goodbye" message.

The issue i am having is that I can not get it to display to OVERALL Millage. it ends after looping 3 times.
I know different loop statements need conditions to be met, but I cant get the FOR loop to work properly. Im getting really frustrated, cause I know this should not be this hard.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int miles,i=3;
    float gallons, mg, overall = 0, avg = 0;
    while(i>0) 
    {
        printf("Enter the gallons used: ");
        scanf("%f", &gallons);
        printf("Enter miles driven: ");
        scanf("%d", &miles);
        mg = miles/gallons;
        printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was : %f\n", mg);
        overall += miles;
        avg += gallons;i--;
    }

    if(gallons == 0) 
    {
        printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (gallons == 0) `...emmm.why?

Comment: Can you sort out the formatting of the code

Comment: The condition `if (gallons == 0)` is never true, hence that print statement never happens.

Comment: there isn't a for loop in your code

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Use a debugger. Learning to use a debugger is as valuable as learning how to code. Learning how to code comes from using a debugger.

Comment: @ChrisTurner There isn't a `for` loop, though the `while` loop he has, as written, should behave the same as a `for` loop which iterates three times.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I am using C-Free. It was no throwing up any errors though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question makes reference to one though

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mis-typed, I was not getting errors, it was just not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, then what is preventing the overall mileage from being printed is the following final `if` statement:

```
if (gallons == 0)
```

If you remove it, then the overall mileage should print.  Use this pattern:

```
while (i > 0)
{
    // your while loop here
}

printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am having a really hard time wrapping brain around loops in this class. That worked. I figured it was something simple. but I have been working on this for a week and was getting irritated.

Comment: @MikeDahl For everyone's sake, maybe you could comment why you had `if (gallons == 0)` in there.  Maybe you were checking for the loop completing, or maybe you wanted to check for divide by zero?

Comment: I had it in there because I'm a moron, and I'm still trying to understand all of this.

Comment: @MikeDahl No issues, your question was way better than what is typical here.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a lot of dumb questions here?

Comment: The thing is, your code was basically fine other than this random `if` statement at the end.  Most questions these days are homework dumps, showing no effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Tim Biegeleisen'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42329071/1783971)s answer:

```
mg = miles/gallons;
```

What if `gallons` equals to `0`? e.g. `0` miles for `0` gallons
This will lead to floating point exception.

A simple `if-else` can solve this problem!

```
if(!gallons)
    mg = 0;  
else
    mg = miles/gallons;
```

Comment: Since it will be a floating point calculation, it'll probably give an infinity as the result, not a crash.  It's curious but these days, one of the very few ways of generating an FPE (floating point exception) is _integer_ division by zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! On my terminal, I was performing integer division which crashed the program on divisor being `0`. So the wrong statement on my part.

Answer (score 0):

This if (`if (gallons == 0) {}`)block is out of while loop.
First, you need to move the if loop inside while loop.
and this if condition should be for variable i as follow and not for gallons.

```
if (i == 0) 
{
    printf("\n\n The overall miles/gallon was: %f\n", overall/avg);
}
```

In this case, after 3 iteration, value of i will be 0 so it will enter into the if block and calculate and print the overall miles/gallon.